# Combing a symlink to an external folder with a Rewrite Rule?

Tags: mod-rewrite, symlink

I've created a symlink in an account to an folder external to that user account (although with the same ownership). The symlink works but I'd like to combine it with a RewriteRule, and I'm having problems with that.

For instance I create the symlink with:

```
ln -s /home/target shortcut
```

And I add the following RewriteRule to .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^shortcut/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) shortcut/index.php?var=$1
```

This however fails.

Yet if instead of being located in an external folder, the *target* folder is in the same folder as the *shortcut* address, then the RewriteRule will work. i.e. it works if the symlink is:

```
ln -s ./target shortcut
```

How might I get the RewriteRule working for the case where the target folder is an external folder?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` will also match the `index` in `index.php`. So you’re getting an infinite loop. Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^shortcut/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ shortcut/index.php?var=$1
```

Comment: Thanks, although I've also attempted this without the regex - e.g.
     RewriteRule ^shortcut/value shortcut/index.php?var=value
Also just tried
     RewriteRule ^shortcut/value$ shortcut/index.php?var=value
As well as the variation you gave. None of these works.